# SQL column AVG() being treated as string and not Ordering By DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

Struggling this the following sql statment.

The database is MySQL with score being DECIMAL(5,1)

Im looking to order by the average score within the column

```
...AVG(COALESCE(score,0)) AS scoreAvg ... ORDER BY scoreAvg DESC
```

but the results are not as expected, I have products with a high score below ones without a score (score is 0).

It lookings like score is being treated as a string, I have tried.

```
CAST(SCORE AS DECIMAL(5,1))
```

but with no luck.

Thank you for any help,

Regards

Comment: Please provide full query, sample data and the erroneous output you are getting.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/564e3b/8 This is a close representation of my code... seems to work in sql fiddle but not on live server.

Answer (score 0):

Try repeating the expression:

```
ORDER BY AVG(COALESCE(score, 0))
```

The first explanation that I think of is that `scoreavg` is already in a table and the ordering is using the column rather than the computed expression.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, scoreAvg is not in the table and also tried repeating the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your value might be in varchar(max)
So you want to convert the varchar to decimal or numeric and add

```
Order  by avg(COALESCE(column name,0))
```

Or

```
Order by avg(coalesce(cast(column name as decimal (5,1)),0.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

After stripping down my sql string, turns out my "image_path" column in TEXT format was causing the issue. Changed it to varchar(255).

I did'nt post it because I didnt think it was relevent.

anyway fixed now.
Must be a bug in MySQL